# Different results of RegEx using JS split function - empty strings in result

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string using a regular expression and split function in JavaScript.
For example, I have a string:
`olej sojowy, sorbitol, czerwień koszenilową`
and my RegEx is:

```
/, (?!(któ))/g
```

When I test it here: 
http://regexr.com/38ps8 I get 2 matches, as expected, so in result I should get 3 elements after split.

But when I try to use this expression in split function:

```
var parts="olej sojowy, sorbitol, czerwień koszenilową".split(/, (?!(któ))/g);
console.log("Num of elements:" + parts.length); 
console.log(parts.join("!\n!"));
```

the result is different and it returns 5 elements in an array, with two additional empty strings:

```
Num of elements:5 
olej sojowy!
!!
!sorbitol!
!!
!czerwień koszenilową
```

Why isn't it working as expected? Is it a problem with split function? Does it use a regular expression in a different way than I would expect?

Edit:
I've just also noticed that if I change my Regular expression to /, /g then I get just what I wanted (3 elements in result), but there are other strings which I don't want to split if there is któ after the coma and space. So why is this operator changing a behaviour of split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Mozilla's JS ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this capability.

If the regex in `split` contains *capturing groups*, the contents of each group is inserted in the result as well. Since you have a capturing group `(któ)`, that is what you get. It is empty because `(?!(któ))` is empty. If you add the text `, któ` anywhere inside your string, you will see it appear:

```
var parts="olej sojowy, któ sorbitol, czerwień koszenilową".split(/, (?!(któ))/g);
```

shows 3 elements. The 2nd is, quite surprising, just `", "`. Then again, it *is* the one where `któ` follows (not sure how I can "prove" that").

If you omit the parentheses inside your lookahead, it works as you expect it to:

```
var parts="olej sojowy, któ sorbitol, czerwień koszenilową".split(/, (?!któ)/g);
```

No capturing groups so you get only the remaining text after removal of the matching regex.

Comment: omitting the parentheses makes no difference. the negative Lookahead asserts that it is impossible to match the regex **któ**

Comment: Thanks! It works without parentheses and now I can understand why it didn't :) Just what I needed.

Comment: @CocoaPuffs: it *does* make a difference, per the documentation. Including parentheses will *always* add "group" matches, empty or otherwise.

Comment: The negative lookahead is pointless though. What is it actually accomplishing?

Comment: @l'L'l: I get different results with and without the lookahead, so it *does* do *something*. Does it return the same matches with and without for you? (See, possibly, the final sentence of the Mozilla quote.)

Comment: @Jongware, [Example one](http://regex101.com/r/wB8jS9) v [Example two](http://regex101.com/r/eG5jH7), and [Example three](http://regex101.com/r/gU5oT1) v [Example four](http://regex101.com/r/kS9zG9). I'm not arguing that those regex functions don't do something, just not within the context of the question. :)

Comment: Perhaps better to post this as a question on its own, so other people can have a look as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's working exactly as it should. You've used `,` as the delimiter so it gives you five elements:

```
[1] olej sojowy
[2]   
[3] sorbitol
[4]   
[5] czerwień koszenilową
```

The empty elements are indicators of where the split(s) are located.

Comment: I don't think it works the way it should. I've just noticed that if I change my Regular expression to `/, /g` then I get just what I wanted (3 elements in result), but there are other strings which I don't want to split if there is `któ` after the coma and space. So why is this operator changing a behaviour of split?

Comment: Your regex pattern is not working the way it should; meaning the negative lookahead does absolutely nothing. Take a look: [**, (?!(anything))**](http://regexr.com/38pse). I'm really not sure what you're wanting to accomplish - the pattern you've got in the negative lookahead **(któ)** is not even in the string of text you're searching.

Comment: Yeah, obviously it is not working the way I want, but the question is why and how can I make it work the way I want? ;) 
And the negative lookahead does nothing, because there is no example there, but look, here's an example where it seems that it works the way I want http://regexr.com/38psh as it doesn't take into account the last coma and space sequence, because there is `któ` after it. But in JS it still finds 9 elements after the split, not 5 after 4 matches, as this websites says.

Comment: Sure, thanks, obviously I could do it, but it would be great to know why it is working that way using RegEx and I'd love to know how to do it using purely RegEx and sadly I can't figure it out :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; regex is designed for finding patterns in strings. When you use those patterns as delimiters (splitting strings) it splits it into an array — There's nothing overly complicated about it really.

Comment: The statement "The empty elements are indicators of where the split(s) are located" is not correct.

Comment: ^ saying something is incorrect without any explanation is more **incorrect**.

Comment: Jongware is right with his answer, just what I needed.

Comment: Well, then: The statement "The empty elements are indicators of where the split(s) are located" is not correct because `split` does not insert empty elements on the position where these splits are located. As @krajol correctly states in the experiment with just the regex `/, /` -- see? No empty elements where the split occurs.

Comment: split puts the matches into an array - The array keys parts[2] and parts[4] are empty, as in undefined, so you're incorrect. The empty array keys are no longer there when eliminating the capture group, or removing the empty keys, but the negative lookahead used in the example doesn't do anything useful anyway. –  l'L'l